# Can the entrance elevator be removed?

Tags: fallout-shelter

In Fallout Shelter, is it possible to remove the elevator at the entrance to the shelter and replace it with a room, or is it there to enforce depth growth?

Can it be done if I send everyone out to the wastelands and remove all the rooms?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Simply sending them into the wasteland won't be enough. This is because even though no one's there, the game still requires you to maintain enough living spaces for your population. So, you can't destroy the barracks which attach to the elevator, preventing you from destroying the elevator.  If you were to kill off (and delete) all your current dwellers this may be possible.

In a new save game I was unable to kill my starting dwellers with fire. They seem totally impervious.  I've sent them out into the wasteland for now, where I can only assume they will not last.

Edit: Well, there were no survivors. With no dwellers remaining, I was able to delete the elevator and replace it with a different room. You may make a great looking vault, but you're unlikely to win any Overseer of the Year awards, having killed off all the existing dwellers. The vault *can* be repopulated, so it's not a game over scenario.

[image: No Elevators]

Comment: Can you build out to a second elevator, then disconnect it from the entrance elevator, then remove the entrance elevator?

Comment: No, because all rooms must stay connected. Due to the placement of the first elevator right at the entrance, when you delete it it would disconnect any other existing rooms.  Thus all rooms must first be deleted.

Comment: @JoshDM Edited with results.

Comment: So, sending them to the wastelands and letting them die "was" enough. :-)

Comment: @JoshDM I also took a couple out within the vault after placing a warehouse. Not sure if unlocking it ended their immunity within the vault or something else.

Comment: This is a brutal cost.  You'll have to get couple dwellers waiting outside, kill everyone, wipe out all your rooms, and then rebuild using fresh dwellers just to get that one square.... but I guess if you're OCD this is what you'll do :)